# How to get remaining value number in array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Basically i want to get the amount and the remaining value number but i didn't get the exact value.

this is my following code

```
    $arr = [5000,2000];
    $return = 0;

    foreach($arr as $val) {
        $sum = (3000 * 10) / 9; 
        if($val < $sum) {
           $v += $val;
           $return =  ($v % $sum);
           if($return == $v)
           $return = 0;
         } else {
          $return = $val;
         }

        $amount = abs($val - $ret);

        print_r("Return : ".$return . " Amount : " .$amount."<br>");
    }
```

the result

```
Return : 5000 Amount : 5000
Return : 0 Amount : 2000
```

but that is wrong value, i want to get like this

```
Return : 1667 Amount : 3333
Return : 2000 Amount : 0
```

Summary :
I want to limit number base on $sum value and return the remaining value and get the amount,
so i write that code above but i can't figure it out.
sorry for my bad english

Thanks, sorry i'm new in php

Comment: Hello HameedR, It will be truly nice to help you out, but you should do your homework first, read, gain knowledge, and then if you faced a problem, come and ask, this is how it works, from your question, i sense that you are at the beginning of the road, just walk a few steps and from there come back and ask if your struggle, how does that sound :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right. You need this.

```
$values = [5000, 2000];

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $n = 3333;
    $remain = $value - $n;

    if ($remain < 0) {
        print 'Return : ' . $value . ' Amount : 0';
    } else {
        print 'Return : ' . $remain . ' Amount : ' . $n;
    }
}
```